# iOS Core Animation Speed Up

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-animation, transition

I am trying to replace one complex view with another complex view using different animations, like moving to left/right/top/bottom. First and second views contains 30-40 subviews (buttons). My code is like this:

```
oldView.alpha = 1;
newView.alpha = 0;
oldView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
newView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -height, width, height);

// begin animation
// setting duration 0.3
// ...

oldView.alpha = 0;
newView.alpha = 1;
oldView.frame = CGRectMake(0, height, width, height);
newView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

// commit animation
// ...
```

It works nice on *iPhone Simulator* and on *iPhone 4S*, but it lags on *iPhone 4*. By lag I mean 12-15 FPS.

How can I speed up this animation?

- Should I use `center` property instead of `frame`?
- Should I render my views to `UIImageView`'s and animate them?
- Should I layout my views in `UIScrollView` and call `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`?

And please, explain me why my animation code so slow? When my two views contains 10-20 buttons - there are no problems with speed...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to post more code as setting a new frame shouldn't be too much of a performance hit.  There are however things you can do with your view's `layer` or in the `drawRect:` that would slow drawing and animation down considerably.

For instance:

```
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 10.0);
myView.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.40;
```

Which adds a nice drop shadow to the view will kill the animation.  So in this instance I turn off the shadows when animating and back on again when done.

Without seeing more of your code it is impossible to say where the problem lies.

**EDIT:**

To speed up the rendering of shadows you can set the `shouldRasterize` property to `YES`.  This forces the layer to create a bitmap of the shadow rather than trying to redraw it every frame.

Comment: My views have 7*5 matrix of buttons with bold system font with only `shadowOffset(0,1)`. I am trying to implement custom calendar control.

Comment: For testing, take the shadow off and see if this improves performance.  If it does you can use the shouldRasterize property and set it to yes.  This stops the shadow being recalc'd every frame.

Comment: You mean shouldRasterize property of each buttons title layer? Interesting property...

Comment: I'll try this way todays evening.

Comment: OK, we need to narrow this down a bit more.  Did you take the shadows off completely?  and if so did this speed things up?

Comment: I removed all shadows from subviews.. Now a am trying to replace move animation with UIScrollView moving...

Comment: Did removing the shadows speed things up?  Just trying to narrow it down.

Comment: No suggnificant performance increases when totally removed 40 text shadows.

Comment: What if i'll use `[view.layer addSublayer:...]` instead of `[view addSubview:...]`?

Comment: Ok, I would first try setting shouldRasterize to YES the entire view's layer and see what happens.

Comment: shouldRasterize don't helps too... Why apple don't have Push transition from view to view?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

- change center instead of frame
- use transform property instead of frame. `oldView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, height);`

Comment: Ok, i'll try it this evening. Maybe you can suggest any article about Core Animation properties performace?

Comment: This is not CoreAnimation. CoreAnimation is about dealing with direct CALayer animations. You are talkimg about UIView animation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1

Comment: But, remember that changing a view's frame will trigger a setNeedsDisplay thus getting a full redraw of the view

Comment: From documentation: "Changing the frame rectangle automatically redisplays the receiver without invoking the `drawRect:` method. If you want the drawRect: method invoked when the frame rectangle changes, set the `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`."

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, if you are using explicit animations yet still setting animatable properties, you'll want to disable implicit animations by using:

```
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
```